# Пишу телеграм бота на telebot. Вроде бы все работает но есть одно НО. Помогите пофиксить

Tags: telegram-bot

Когда пользователь пишет неправильное число. Бот начинает спамить Вы не угадали число! Попробуй еще раз. (кол-во попыток = 1... до бесконечности)
Это происходит из-за того что он считывает информацию всех сообщений, а мне надо чтобы он считывал инфу от сообщения пользователя. А как пофиксить я не знаю.
Помогите пожалуйста!!!!

Вот код:

`

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
import requests
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('\U0001F3AE Угадай число')

    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name} \U0001F44B !\n \nВыберите какую либо функцию.',
                     reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.text == '\U0001F3AE Угадай число':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали функцию "\U0001F3AE Угадай число".')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до 10.\n\nПопробуй угадать его:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number2)

def number2(message):
    n = random.randint(1, 10)
    a = 0
    win = False
    while win == False:
        a += 1
        un = float(message.text)
        if un == n:
            win = True
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Поздравляю! Вы угадали число {n}, с {a} попыток')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы не угадали число! Попробуй еще раз. (кол-во попыток = {a})')
```

bot.polling(none_stop=True)`